# Is there a shortcut to change to a different tool while typing in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I am just wondering if there is a way to use keyboard shortcuts while using the "T" Type tool. For example, while I am creating text with the words "hello," and I want to move to the selection tool, I would end up typing "helloa," because "a" is the selection too. Is there a command/option/shift ability so that text is not written while using this tool?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use ctrl + enter to exit the type tool

Answer (score 5):

Hit the the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to **commit** the text.

Note: ENTER *not* Return. They are *not* the same key.

If using Return because your keyboard has no Enter key.... 
you need to hold <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> Then hit the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Then you can hit any other tool shortcut to switch tools.

---

You could also hit the √ in the control bar to commit the text. Or hit the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key and you'll be asked, via a popup, if you want to commit the text or remove it.

Comment: The "enter" key on the number-pad of my keyboard is the one I use. As @Scott says... not your "main" enter key so to speak. I remember the day I learnt this myself! Such an odd shortcut, and SO useful